# Spliting Username instead of ID inside of Array

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm creating a system that look like post-comments system like facebook's. I use codeigniter firstly.

I need to use 3 table for getting all datas. (username from users, post from posts, comments from comments)

```
$data = $this->post_model->getPosts();

        foreach ($data as $data) {
            $user = $this->members_model->memberData($data['uye']);
            $comments = $this->post_model->getComments($data['id']);
            $new_data[] = array('nick' => $user['nick'], 'post' => $data['post'], 'comments'=>$comments);
        }
```

Output

```
Array (
     [0] => Array (
              [nick] => yusufalibozkir 
              [post] => try.
              [comments] => Array (
                             [0] => Array (
                                    [id] => 1 
                                    [user] => 1 
                                    [comment] => comment try 
                                    [post] => 1
                                   )
                             )
             )
      )
```

I want to split parameter of user that is 1 as username that's id is 1. What is your suggestions?

Comment: Sorry i dont know what you mean? `I want to split parameter of user that is 1 as username that's id is 1`

Comment: Also, i would consider changing this `foreach($data as $data)`

Comment: Adding your expected output might make us understand what you want

Comment: @AlexP I want to change id=> 1 as id=>username

Comment: Then you need to change your getComments method... and it's hard to help you on invisible code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is very very unclear, but did you mean something like this?

```
$alldata = $this->post_model->getPosts();

    foreach ($alldata as $data) {
        $user = $this->members_model->memberData($data['uye']);
        $comments = $this->post_model->getComments($data['id']);
        $comments['id'] = $user['nick'];
        $new_data[] = array('nick' => $user['nick'], 'post' => $data['post'], 'comments'=>$comments);
    }
```